# Algorithm - String matching based on repetition factors

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching, prefix, repeat

I have three strings as the input (A,B,C).

A = "SLOVO", B = "WORD", C =

[image]

And I need to find algorithm which decide, if the string C is a concatenation of infinite repetiton strings A and B. Example of repetition: A^2 = "SLOVOSLOVO" and in the string C is first 8 letters "SLOVOSLO" from "SLOVOSLOVO". String B is similar.

**My idea for algorithm:**

```
index_A = 0; //index of actual letter of string A
index_B = 0;

Go throught the hole string C from 0 to size(C)
{
  Pick the actual letter from C (C[i])
  if(C[i] == A[index_A] && C[i] != B[index_B])
  {
   index_A++;
   Go to next letter in C 
  }
  else if(C[i] == B[index_B] && C[i] != A[index_A])
  {
   index_B++;
   Go to next letter in C 
  }
  else if(C[i] == B[index_B] && C[i] == A[index_A])
  {
   Now we couldn´t decice which way to go, so we should test both options (maybe recusrsion)
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
}
```

It´s only quick description of the algorithm but I hope you understand main idea of this algorithm should do. Is this the way of solving this problem good? Do you have better solution? Or some tips?

Comment: What language are you gonna write this in?

Comment: Finally in pseudocode or probably in C. Sorry, that I write the code in "not language" but I hope you understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you've got the problem that every regular expression matcher has. Yes, you would need to test both options, and if one doesn't work you will have to [backtrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to the other. Expressing your loop over the string recursively can help here.

However, there is also a way to try both options at the same time. See the popular article [*Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast*](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) for the idea - you basically keep track of all possible positions in the two strings during the iteration of `c`. The required lookup structure would have a size of `len(A)*len(B)`, as you can just use a modulus for the string position instead of storing the position in the infinite, repeated string.

```
// some (pythonic) pseudocode for this:

isIntermixedRepetition(a, b, c)
    alen = length(a)
    blen = length(c)
    pos = new Set() // to store tuples
                    // could be implemented as bool array of dimension alen*blen
    pos.add( [0,0] ) // init start pos
    for ci of c
        totest = pos.getContents() // copy and
        pos.clear()                // empty the set
        for [indexA, indexB] of totest
            if a[indexA] == ci
                pos.add( [indexA + 1 % alen, indexB] )
            // no else
            if b[indexB] == ci
                pos.add( [indexA, indexB + 1 % blen] )
        if pos.isEmpty
            break
    return !pos.isEmpty
```

Comment: What do you mean with "try both options at the same time" and "keep track of all possible positions in the two strings"? Can you write about your idea more? I don´t fully understand it. Thx.

Comment: Have you read the article I've linked? If yes, I'll try to write some example pseudo code.

Comment: Yes, I have read it. Now I know what do you mean. Can you advice me, how I can try both options at the same time in my code? Or write some quick description of pseudocode for better explenation?